# union of two columns of a tsv file

Tags: linux, graph, cut, csv

I've a file which stores a directed graph. Each line is represented as

node1 TAB node2 TAB weight

I want to find the set of nodes. Is there a better way of getting union? My current solution involves creating temporary files:

```
cut -f1 input_graph | sort | uniq > nodes1
cut -f2 input_graph | sort | uniq > nodes2
cat nodes1 nodes2 | sort | uniq > nodes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{ cut -f1 input_graph; cut -f2 input_graph; } | sort | uniq
```

No need to sort twice.

The { cmd1; cmd2; } syntax is equivalent to (cmd1; cmd2) but may avoid a subshell.

In another language (e.g. Perl), you could slurp the first column in a hash and then process the second column sequentially.

With Bash only, you can avoid temporary files by using the syntax `cat <(cmd1) <(cmd2)`. Bash takes care of creating temporary file descriptors and setting up pipelines.

In a script (where you may want to avoid requiring bash), if you end up needing temporary files, use `mktemp`

Comment: can you elaborate on `mktemp`?

Comment: That was a marginal point, an FYI for your future scripting habits (which is why I mentioned it last). E.g. in your ORIGINAL code, you could use `mktemp` to generate temporary file names (instead of hard-coding filenames "nodes1" and "nodes2"): `NODES1=$(mktemp); cut -f1 input_graph | sort | uniq > "$NODES1"`. But of course there is no actual need for temporary files of any sort, with hard-coded names or not :)